# Using a single Android handler repeatedly

Tags: android, timer, handler

I have been trying to create a simple Simon memory game which I completed but the code was not professional, I am redoing it and hoping to learn how to do it right. The only part I cannot figure out is how to use a handler correctly, after a week of trying to do this I need some help. So I have an array full of numbers for now 20 numbers, each random between 1 and 4. Some code to call a certain method depending on the number in the array, for testing I want to run the game to play through the first 20 levels automatically, here is the game loop code:

```
// First time pass 1 to Level method
public void Level(int lvl) {

    // for 20 times, once for each number in the array index
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {

        // lvl is initialsed to 1 so the first time it does this once
        for (int i = 0; i <= lvl; i++) {

            // Call checknumber method and pass arrayindex value
            checknumber(array[i]);
        }

        lvl++;  
    }   
}
```

So the above code lights up a color and plays a sound rapidly, I tried to do this in my second for loop but it demanded that the i variable was set to final which didn't work, again I tried to read up on why it needs to be final and couldn't understand it:

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= lvl; i++) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Call checknumber method and pass arrayindex value
                    checknumber(array[i]);
                }
            }, amount);

        }
```

So in my checknumber method I have this:

```
public void checknumber(int a) {
    //if number passed is 1 then play green button
    if (a == 1) {
        green();
    }

    //if number passed is 2 then play green button
    if (a == 2) {
        red();
    }

    //if number passed is 3 then play green button
    if (a == 3) {
        yellow();
    }

    //if number passed is 4 then play green button
    if (a == 4) {
        blue();
    }
}
```

Which calls these methods:

```
public void green() {
    s1();
    b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b1tlchanged);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b1tl);
        }
    }, amount);
}

public void red() {
    s2();
    b2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b2trchanged);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            b2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b2tr);
        }
    }, amount);
}

public void yellow() {
    s3();
    b3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b3blchanged);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            b3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b3bl);
        }
    }, amount);
}

public void blue() {
    s4();
    b4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b4brchanged);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            b4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b4br);
        }
    }, amount);
}
```

You can see the current handlers I have and they do not work because they are in the wrong place I think, they should be in my for loop is what I think but I do not know what is the best solution here and how to do it. Should I have multiple Handlers, or just one, I felt a single Handler was best.

I need to play a colour and sound then half a second later another the next sound and colour so a half a second in between each method call, should I try pausing the activity after each method call? Any advice on this would be great as I need to get better with my programming. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

definitely use one Handler, and avoid Runnables as they are poor folks when it comes to params passing, use Messages instead handling them in handleMessage()

Comment: Can you please provide an example? Thank you! :)

Comment: skip SO links, read the rest http://www.google.com/search?q=handler+handlemessage+example